# overwrite a json file with objects from another json file using jq

Tags: json, file, merge, jq

MODIFIED:

Hello I'm having problems on merging 2 files basically I have 2 json files with this structure:

```
[
  {
    "uri": "some/url.feature",
    "id": "safety-tests",
    "keyword": "Feature",
    "name": "Safety Tests",
    "description": "Some description",
    "line": 2,
    "tags": [
      {
        "name": "@sometag",
        "line": 1
      }
    ],
    "elements": [
      {
        "id": "some-element-id",
        "keyword": "Scenario Outline",
        "name": ": Some scenario name",
        "description": "",
        "line": 46,
        "type": "scenario",
        "tags": [
          {
            "name": "@sometag",
            "line": 1
          },
          {
            "name": "@someothertag",
            "line": 31
          }
        ],
        "before": [
          {
            "match": {
              "location": "some/test/file.rb:201"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 15000
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "location": "some/other/file.rb:5"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 1722192000
            }
          }
        ],
        "steps": [
          {
            "keyword": "Given ",
            "name": "Some step name",
            "line": 46,
            "output": [
              "Some output"
            ],
            "match": {
              "location": "some/other/path/to/other/file.rb:137"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 989158000
            }
          },
          {
            "keyword": "When ",
            "name": "some other step",
            "line": 46,
            "output": [
              "WARNING: static wait for 1 seconds."
            ],
            "match": {
              "location": "some/other/path/to/other/file.rb:80"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 2700052000
            }
          },
          {
            "keyword": "And ",
            "name": "Some other name",
            "line": 46,
            "match": {
              "location": "some/other/path/to/other/file.rb:38"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 954225000
            }
          },
          {
            "keyword": "Then ",
            "name": "Some other step name",
            "line": 46,
            "match": {
              "location": "some/other/path/to/other/file.rb:2"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 38792000
            }
          },
          {
            "keyword": "And ",
            "name": "And again some other step name",
            "line": 46,
            "match": {
              "location": "some/other/path/to/other/file.rb:2"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 39268000
            }
          },
          {
            "keyword": "And ",
            "name": "Some other step name",
            "line": 46,
            "match": {
              "location": "some/other/path/to/other/file.rb:2"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 55637000
            }
          },
          {
            "keyword": "And ",
            "name": "Some other step name",
            "line": 46,
            "match": {
              "location": "some/other/path/to/other/file.rb:2"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 38375000
            }
          },
          {
            "keyword": "When ",
            "name": "Some other step name",
            "line": 46,
            "match": {
              "location": "some/other/path/to/other/file.rb:12"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 751416000
            }
          },
          {
            "keyword": "And ",
            "name": "Some other step name",
            "line": 46,
            "match": {
              "location": "some/other/path/to/other/file.rb:2"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 28043000
            }
          },
          {
            "keyword": "Then ",
            "name": "Some other step name",
            "line": 46,
            "match": {
              "location": "some/other/path/to/other/file.rb:20"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 5204000
            }
          }
        ],
        "after": [
          {
            "match": {
              "location": "some/other/path/to/other/file.rb:91"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 20000
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "location": "some/other/path/to/other/file.rb:52"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 5585000
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "location": "some/other/path/to/other/file.rb:27"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 168146000
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "location": "some/other/path/to/other/file.rb:428"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 62000
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "some-element-id",
        "keyword": "Scenario Outline",
        "name": ": Some scenario name",
        "description": "",
        "line": 46,
        "type": "scenario",
        "tags": [
          {
            "name": "@sometag",
            "line": 1
          },
          {
            "name": "@someothertag",
            "line": 31
          }
        ],
        "before": [
          {
            "match": {
              "location": "some/test/file.rb:201"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 15000
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "location": "some/other/file.rb:5"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 1722192000
            }
          }
        ],
        "steps": [
          {
            "keyword": "Given ",
            "name": "Some step name",
            "line": 46,
            "output": [
              "Some output"
            ],
            "match": {
              "location": "some/other/path/to/other/file.rb:137"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 989158000
            }
          },
          {
            "keyword": "When ",
            "name": "some other step",
            "line": 46,
            "output": [
              "WARNING: static wait for 1 seconds."
            ],
            "match": {
              "location": "some/other/path/to/other/file.rb:80"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 2700052000
            }
          },
          {
            "keyword": "And ",
            "name": "Some other name",
            "line": 46,
            "match": {
              "location": "some/other/path/to/other/file.rb:38"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 954225000
            }
          },
          {
            "keyword": "Then ",
            "name": "Some other step name",
            "line": 46,
            "match": {
              "location": "some/other/path/to/other/file.rb:2"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 38792000
            }
          },
          {
            "keyword": "And ",
            "name": "And again some other step name",
            "line": 46,
            "match": {
              "location": "some/other/path/to/other/file.rb:2"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 39268000
            }
          },
          {
            "keyword": "And ",
            "name": "Some other step name",
            "line": 46,
            "match": {
              "location": "some/other/path/to/other/file.rb:2"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 55637000
            }
          },
          {
            "keyword": "And ",
            "name": "Some other step name",
            "line": 46,
            "match": {
              "location": "some/other/path/to/other/file.rb:2"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 38375000
            }
          },
          {
            "keyword": "When ",
            "name": "Some other step name",
            "line": 46,
            "match": {
              "location": "some/other/path/to/other/file.rb:12"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 751416000
            }
          },
          {
            "keyword": "And ",
            "name": "Some other step name",
            "line": 46,
            "match": {
              "location": "some/other/path/to/other/file.rb:2"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 28043000
            }
          },
          {
            "keyword": "Then ",
            "name": "Some other step name",
            "line": 46,
            "match": {
              "location": "some/other/path/to/other/file.rb:20"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 5204000
            }
          }
        ],
        "after": [
          {
            "match": {
              "location": "some/other/path/to/other/file.rb:91"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 20000
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "location": "some/other/path/to/other/file.rb:52"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 5585000
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "location": "some/other/path/to/other/file.rb:27"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 168146000
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "location": "some/other/path/to/other/file.rb:428"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 62000
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

where `elements` can contain **any number of objects** on either file. These are test results from cucumber so usually file A contains more elements than file B since file B is a re-run of the failed tests in file A.

For example. If on the first pass we ran 100 tests, file A `elements` array will contain 100 objects of with the format described above. However if from those 100 tests 50 of them failed, file B `elements` array will contain 50 objects. What I want to do is to overwrite file A `elements` array with file B's just adding the elements that repeat in both. Something like

if file A had

```
"elements":[{a:1, b:2, c:3, d:2, e:9, f:4}]
```

and file B had

```
"elements":[{d:5}]
```

I'd like the new file to have

```
"elements":[{a:1, b:2, c:3, d:5, e:9, f:4}]
```

So far I've got

```
jq '.[].elements' path/to/file/b > path/to/new/file
jq --argfile file path/to/new/file '.[].elements += $file' path/to/file/b
```

That puts together whatever file B contains in the `elements` array within the `elements` array in file A but doesn't remove the duplicated object inside of it.

I tried to use `unique` but no clue on how to use it. Any ideas?

After a few responses here I got

```
jq --argfile b ~/Desktop/cucumber-rerun.json '.[0].elements[4] *= $b[0].elements[0]' ~/Desktop/cucumber.json
```

to works since, in my actual example, I knew the element 4 in file A is the one I want to overwrite with the 1 and only element in file B. However that doesn't work for me since both files are autogenerated and the order of the objects is unknown.

I'd like to have a command that sees both files compared them and autodetects repeated objects from A and B and overwrite those in A with those in B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution which uses [Object Multiplication](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Multiplication,division,modulo:%2A,/,and%).  Assuming your data is in `A.json` and `B.json`:

```
$ jq -M --argfile b B.json '.[0].elements[0] *= $b[0].elements[0]' A.json
```

produces

```
[
  {
    "uri": "https://someurl.com",
    "id": "some-id",
    "keyword": "SomeKeyword",
    "name": "Some Name",
    "description": "Some description for that test result",
    "line": 2,
    "tags": [
      {
        "name": "@sometag",
        "line": 1
      }
    ],
    "elements": [
      {
        "a": 5,
        "b": 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This approach is easily generalized if your arrays contain more data but you'll need to understand how corresponding elements should be identified.

---

Regarding the revised question, here is a filter which updates objects of `A.json` with corresponding objects of `B.json` having the same `.id`:

```
def INDEX(stream; idx_expr):
  reduce stream as $row ({};
    .[$row|idx_expr| if type != "string" then tojson else . end] |= $row);

def merge_by_id(a;b):
  if b then INDEX(a[];.id) * INDEX(b[];.id) | map(.) else a end;

  INDEX($b[];.id) as $i
| map( .elements = merge_by_id(.elements; $i[.id].elements) )
```

For example if the above filter is in `filter.jq`, `A.json` contains the revised sample data and `B.json` contains

```
[
  {
    "id": "safety-tests",
    "elements": [
      {
        "id": "some-element-id",
        "description": "updated description"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The command

```
$ jq -M --argfile b B.json -f filter.jq A.json
```

generates the result

```
[
  {
    "uri": "some/url.feature",
    "id": "safety-tests",                      <------ top level .id
    ...
    "elements": [
      {
        "id": "some-element-id",               <------ element .id
        "keyword": "Scenario Outline",
        "name": ": Some scenario name",
        "description": "updated description",  <------ updated value
        "line": 46,
        "type": "scenario",
        ...
```

---

Note that the above solution assumes the `.id` of the elements in `A.json` are unique otherwise `merge_by_id` won't produce the desired output.  In that case the following filter should suffice:

```
def INDEX(stream; idx_expr):
  reduce stream as $row ({};
    .[$row|idx_expr| if type != "string" then tojson else . end] |= $row);

  (INDEX($b[];.id) | map_values(INDEX(.elements[];.id))) as $i
| map( $i[.id] as $o | if $o then .elements |= map($o[.id]//.) else . end )
```

This filter only requires the `.id` of the objects in `B.json` to be unique.  If it's possible for there to be non-unique elements in both `A.json` and `B.json` then a more sophisticated mapping then this one will be required.

Here is a version of the filter with comments:

```
def INDEX(stream; idx_expr):
  reduce stream as $row ({};
    .[$row|idx_expr| if type != "string" then tojson else . end] |= $row);

  # first create a lookup table for elements from B.json
  (                                         #       [{id:x, elements:[{id:y, ...}]}]
      INDEX($b[];.id)                       # -> {x: {id:x, elements:[{id:y, ...}]}..}
    | map_values(INDEX(.elements[];.id))    # -> {x: {y: {id:y, ...}}}
  ) as $i

  # update A.json objects
| map(                                      # for each object in A.json
    $i[.id] as $o                           # do we have updated values from B.json ?
  | if $o then .elements |= map($o[.id]//.) # if so then replace corresponding elements
    else . end                              # otherwise leave object unchanged
  )
```

Comment: This seems to be close but seems to substitute the first element of A with the first element of B... the objects might not be on the same position though in my case and I want it to recognize them and overwrite the correct one.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant that you need to understand the correspondence if your data is more complex then the sample you provided.  As is your question doesn't state how this should be handled.  I can easily revise the answer if you amend your question with more details to cover the various cases such as what to do when A.json or B.json's top level array contains more then one element or when the .elements array contains more then one element but at the moment you've left things ambiguous.  A more complete example would be best.

Comment: @Gus The solution given already solves the `"elements"` cases of A: `[{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3, "d":2, "e":9, "f":4}]` and B: `[{"d":5}]` since each of those arrays contains a single object.  What you haven't described are `"elements"` cases such as `[]`, `[{}]`, `[{"a":1},{"a":2},{"a":3}]`, `[{"a":1},{"b":2,"a":1},{"b":1}]` and so on.  What would you expect if A or B had any of those as `"elements":` ?   E.g. if A has `"elements":[{"a":1},{"b":2,"a":1},{"b":1}]` and B has `"elements":[{"c":1},{"b":0,"c":2,"a":9}]` what should the final result be?

Comment: I think that I would want to the final thing to be `"elements":[{"a":1},{"b":0,"c":2,"a":9},{"b":1}]` but Im not sure at this point... from my edited question I wanted to use `"elements": [{"id": "some-element-id",...`  that ID as a comparison point

Comment: If the *ith* element of A is updated with the *ith* element of B I think the result would be `[{"a":1,"c":1},{"b":0,"c":2","a":9},{"b":1}]`.  Getting back to your revised question do you mean that if A elements are `[{"id":1,"a":1},{"id":2,"b":1}]` and B elements are `[{"id":2,"a":2},{"id":3,"a":1}]` would the result be `[{"id":1,"a":1},"{"id":2,"a":2,"b":2},{"id":3,"a":3}]` ?

Comment: I've added an example for your revised question.

Comment: I applied it to my actual example and it seems to kinda work, but the original file overwrites itself too kinda weirdly... Can I have an email or slack or twitter were I can send the exact example?

Comment: Why not post it on jqplay.org or tio.run ?   As to the overwriting, that's probably a result of the `*` which does recursive merging.  That seemed appropriate at first but you might want to try `+` instead.  E.g. `def merge_by_id(a;b): if b then INDEX(a[];.id) + INDEX(b[];.id) | map(.) else a end;`  Another alternative would be to define an explicit function that takes two objects and does the merge however you need.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/gustavoriveray/06a6897fd92e73dcd9e6b93a282485a3

Comment: I believe [this version](https://gist.github.com/jq170727/c3643ed5a9b5070bf9eddab94d5c0aea) which uses `+` instead of `*` will solve your problem.

Comment: I don't think it does. Check the diff between the original and the result [here](https://www.diffchecker.com/G5F3OaTX) the first set of differences between lines 592 and 777 is what I expect. But don't know what's happening at the bottom after line 6743. Thanks for all the help by the way

Comment: I believe I found the issue - you have [duplicates in the element .id values of your cucumber.json](https://jqplay.org/s/BSwuzKZ2-w).  I've updated the answer with a filter that should handle this and I've pushed an update to the [gist](https://gist.github.com/jq170727/c3643ed5a9b5070bf9eddab94d5c0aea)

Comment: Not quite yet. It seems that it gets rid of the duplicated object in A but doesn't paste that object from B. Check [this](https://www.diffchecker.com/Ks2Z9XDj) diff, that's the original A vs your out.json. Im looking for something like [this](https://www.diffchecker.com/BM3RckDn) which I accomplished with `jq --argfile b ~/Desktop/cucumber-rerun.json '.[0].elements[4] *= $b[0].elements[0]' ~/Desktop/cucumber.json` but that won't apply to all, just to this example

Comment: I think it works.  In particular see the [`diff.json`](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jq170727/c3643ed5a9b5070bf9eddab94d5c0aea/raw/2dc69dc056c34008178638f1d25fe790ef26cfea/diff.json) and `out.json.gz` generated by revised `Makefile` in [gist](https://gist.github.com/jq170727/c3643ed5a9b5070bf9eddab94d5c0aea) using data from your [earlier gist](https://gist.github.com/gustavoriveray/06a6897fd92e73dcd9e6b93a282485a3).  I think the earlier `out.json.gz` was only different from expected because I accidently added something generated with a smaller `cucumber-rerun.json`. Try it with your data.

Comment: Damn! it does work!... Nice now, can you explain to me the response? filter was

     ```def INDEX(stream; idx_expr):
      reduce stream as $row ({};
        .[$row|idx_expr| if type != "string" then tojson else . end] |= $row);

      (INDEX($b[];.id) | map_values(INDEX(.elements[];.id))) as $i
    | map( $i[.id] as $o | if $o then .elements |= map($o[.id]//.) else . end )```
and jq command is `jq -M --argfile b cucumber-rerun.json -f filter.jq cucumber.json > out.json` just for everyone else in the future?

Comment: Are the comments in the final version of the answer unclear?  What bits need clarification?

Answer (score 0):

There are two key insights required to solve your problem concisely:

- if A and B are two objects, then you can combine them with priority being given to B by writing: A + B
- To update an object "in place", we can use |= or += as appropriate.

In your case, we can apply these insights by writing:

```
.[0].elements[0] += $B[0].elements[0]
```

assuming an invocation along the following lines:

```
jq --argfile B B.json -f combine.jq A.json
```

#### Output

With your input, the output includes:

```
"elements": [
  {
    "a": 5,
    "b": 2
  }
]
```

As per the requirements.

#### Further notes

To overwrite A.json with the output produced by the above invocation of jq, you might want to use `sponge`, but please be aware of the risks.

If you don't want to use `--argfile` for whatever reason, you could use `--slurpfile` instead, but then you'd have to write `$B[0][0]`

Comment: (1) The "elements" output produced by the program is exactly as you specified. (2) Your new requirements are unclear.  Maybe you should ask a new SO question?

Comment: this `jq --argfile b ~/Desktop/cucumber-rerun.json '.[0].elements[4] *= $b[0].elements[0]' ~/Desktop/cucumber.json` solved it for this particular case. However Im not going to always know the order of the elements. I'd like for it to auto detect which one is the one repeated and substitute it

Comment: What does "auto-detect" mean?  You should start a new SO question, specifying your requirements and giving concise examples.

Comment: @Gus - As best I can tell, the solution given here matches your requirements.  You should come up with a MINIMAL COMPLETE example that shows expected inputs and the expected output (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).