# NodeSass - override values from json with values from another json

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, node-sass-json-importer

I'd like to have in my Angular project two theme files, one with default values, another with custom values, like this:

theme-colors-default.json

```
{  
  "colors": {
    "primaryColor": "yellow",
    "secondaryColor": "blue"
  }
}
```

theme-colors-custom.json

```
{
  "colors": {
    "primaryColor": "green"
  }
}
```

Then I have a file, where I import both themes with help of `node-sass-json-importer`.

_variables.scss

```
@import 'src/themes/theme-colors-default.json';
@import 'src/themes/theme-colors-custom.json';
```

Now, if I access `map-get($colors, 'secondaryColor')`, I get default bootstrap color. Is it somehow possible to arrange some kind of 'overriding', to override only values present in custom theme?

The only way I can see now is to copy the default theme and change only values that need to be changed, but I don't like this way very much.

Comment: See this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47023283/14945696

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour How can I use this in my Angular project? I've never heard about it. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I have pasted this link by wrong (Beacause JQ is Programming Language in Linux So it is not related to Angular) But as my knowledge of JS you must open two json files then edit them then save them that is what I thinking about to solve this problem .